# Is it possible to download csv files inside Google drive shared folder through HTTP Request of Google Drive API?

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I wanna download files inside a google drive shared folder in which I have editor permission.

I am planning to implement that function as cronjob.

So I would like to ask if I can do that with just HTTP request or use google API library and write some codes in order to achieve what I want?

I'm using Laravel PHP.

Can you tell me the workflow that I should use?

Thank you so much in advance. :D

Following is sketch codes what I think of.

```
$files = HTTP::get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files',
                 ['key'=> myApiKey , 
                  'q'=> "parents in '{folder_id}' and trashed = false' , 
                  'supportsAllDrives' => true,
                 'includeItemsFromAllDrives'=>true, ]);
foreach($files as $file){
    //Here I will download the file.
}
```

Comment: Did you try running the sketch code? When you do come back with some errors for us to see and then we can help

Comment: @RiggsFolly I run the code above and var_dump($files) return  ``` "code" => 403
    "message" => "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file." ```. I assume the folder id is the words behind the url of https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/{this id}.  Am I using the correct folder id?

Comment: That's not going to work without an authorization header.  You need an access token to access private user data.  API key will only grant you access to public data.

Comment: @DaImTo Oh I tried as you said and it works !!! Thanks a lot :D. Now let me try downloading those file.

Comment: @DaImTo Can I ask one more question? Can I download the csv file through HTTP request?